# page can't be displayed when redirect to https

Tags: java, http, web, https, web.xml

This is my web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

It was working but suddenly it has stopped working and when I run the application I get:

> "This page can’t be displayed
>
> •Make sure the web address http:// localhost:8080 is correct.
>
> •Look for the page with your search engine.
>
> •Refresh the page in a few minutes."

Comment: Is your server up and running?

Comment: @abl Yes its up and running